# separating float & String in Object in Java

Tags: java, sorting, object, import

I have a two dimentional Object that in Rows are String Names & in Columns are float Numbers

I want to sort float Numbers but when I send it to bubbleSort Function it gives me an error that can not use < or >  .

How can I Sort Numbers beside their Names ?

for Object in Java what should I import ?

```
public static void bubbleSort(Object student[][] , int length)
{ 
    int w,x; 
    float place; 
    for(w=length-1; w>0 ;w--)
    { 
        for(x=0; x<w ; x++)
        { 
            if(student[x][1]<student[x+1][1])
            {     
                place=student[x][1]; 
                student[x][1]=student[x+1][1]; 
                student[x+1][1]=place; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}//bubbleSort
```

thanks

Comment: Show us the code. And the error.

Comment: This is my bubbleSort Function :public static void bubbleSort(Object student[][] , int length){
int w,x;
float place;
for(w=length-1; w>0 ;w--){
 for(x=0; x<w ; x++){
  if(student[x][1]<student[x+1][1]){
   place=student[x][1];
   student[x][1]=student[x+1][1];
   student[x+1][1]=place;
  }
  
 }
}
 
 
}//bubbleSort

Comment: You don't need to import anything to use object.

Comment: Edit it into the question and format it as code; this is horribly unreadable.

Comment: I've done it though ^^

Comment: @ChristianSt. How ? can u explain a little more ?

Comment: ... this is your code -.-

Comment: Can you show us how you call that function with example data?

Answer (score 0):

Since the array contains Object and not primitives, you can't use < and > . . . but if you cast the Object to a float beforehand, you can. Here's some unrelated example code so that you can see how the cast is achieved...you're on your own from there.

```
Object o;
o = 3.1415F;

System.out.println(o);
System.out.println("Casting to float and printing: " + (float) o);
Object p = 4.1415F;
System.out.println("p is " + p);
System.out.println("p < o? " + ((float) p < (float) o));
```

Answer (score 0):

`student[x][1]` and `student[x+1][1]` is of type `Object` you can not use it in Arithmetic operations like < or >, first cast your values to float type then do the comparison.

```
public static void bubbleSort(Object student[][] , int length)
{ 
    int w,x; 
    float place; 
    for(w=length-1; w>0 ;w--)
    { 
        for(x=0; x<w ; x++)
        { 
            float fValue1 = (float)student[x][1];
            float fValue2 = (float)student[x+1][1];
            if(fValue1 < fValue2)
            {     
                place=(float) student[x][1]; 
                student[x][1]=student[x+1][1]; 
                student[x+1][1]=place; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}//bubbleSort
```

Comment: Thanks , But it errors that you can not cast from Object to float .